# MySQL Privileges To Create Database

Tags: mysql, database, database-management

Is there a way to create a user in MySQL that have login access but no databases, but it allows the user to create a new database to a limit of 5 or what ever I decide.

So basically what I want is to give a user access to create his own databases, but I dont want him to see other databases, also he should be limited to create only 5 databases

Comment: "*to give a user access to create his own databases*" - by granting the "create database" privilege? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_create but I don't think you can limit that to only 5 databases.

Comment: Ok, ill go another route, will create a managment console might be easier (something like cpanel)

Comment: The  scenario you are asking is exactly the one maintained by hosting providers creating a user and adding priveleges as in cpanel might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no notion of "Database Owner" or "Database Creator" in MySQL, therefore there is no way to limit the number of databases created by a user.

*Note: it is possible to put some [restrictions at account-level](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-resources.html), but not the ones you are looking for. You will need a [third-party management tool](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13562388/1446005) for this.*

Comment: Cool, I will then look at cpanel or create my own